# Higher order component for verifying authentication

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am new to React.js. On the server side, I am using Passport.js for social authentication setting a cookie. With that cookie I am verifying on the client side with a higher order component (HOC). This component will check a specific value in the decoded cookie for every secure component that is being rendered. Is this the correct way to do it?

**HOC.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import jwt from 'jwt-simple';


function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

export default function(ComposedComponent) {
    class Authentication extends React.Component{
        static contextTypes = {
            router:React.PropTypes.object
        };
        componentWillMount(){
            let specificCookie = readCookie('peace');
            if(specificCookie !== null ){
                let decoded = jwt.decode(token,'NONOE');

                if(decoded.verify !== "falseAlarm"){
                    this.context.router.push('/')

                }
            }else{
                this.context.router.push('/')
            }

        }
        render(){

            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>
        }
    }

    return Authentication
}
```